# How to write the relative path expression (XPath) to extract the email address from the following screenshot?

Tags: html, css, xml, automationanywhere

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRqCf.png)

I see that the absolute path keeps on changing.

1) //div[@id='details']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRqCf.png)/div[2]/dl[8]/dd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRqCf.png)

2) //div[@id='details']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRqCf.png)/div[2]/dl[7]/dd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRqCf.png)

Need your help in writing the relative expression in place of the absolute expression.

This is for using with Automation Anywhere for automating a website.
Website:https://www.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-male-sp-nz.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please enter a description for your image specifying what it is

Comment: Hi @jo_va, In the following screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRqCf.png) I am trying to access the Email address from the website which keeps on changing after every refresh. I see that the absolute path keeps on changing. So I am trying to write a relative path so that the email is captured correctly even after the page is refreshed. This is for project in which I am extracting data from a website using the AutomationAnywhere software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
//dl[dt/text()='Email Address']/dd
```

It means:

1. Find a `dl` element that has a direct child `dt` element with text 'Email Address'
2. Find a direct child element `dd` under the `dl` element

You can then use it in **Object Cloning**, for example.

Comment: thank you. It worked. Could you also point me towards the learning resources available online or books that I can refer, to enhance my knowledge on Xpath?

Comment: I have learned it mainly from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp). Start with simple element finding by different attributes (like AA does with the @id attribute), that's what you'll need most of the time. More powerful locators are Axes (using node relationships) or functions (for example, find a table with at least 3 rows). Always keep in mind that AA uses XPath 1.0 in XML commands and Object Cloning, some functions are available only from higher versions (like Replace)